# GTX 670 video, audio and mouse lag

Tags: windows-8, video, graphics-card, lag

I got some stutter recently. without my GTX installed and using the intel hd 4000 graphics there is no issue. However after installing my Nvidia card and drivers I have some random stuttering.

This happens with youtube, other video sites and even my Windows Media Player Classic. The stutter causes video, audio and mouse to stutter.

Any help would be great. I am on a Asus P8Z77 -V Pro. Intel 3570k. 8 gigs Gskill ripjaw ram. Windows 8

Driver is 314.14

Comment: open Taskmanager and look if you get high DPC/Interrupt usage. If yes, use xperf to see the cause: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263

Comment: I cannot use that as I have windows 8. States they are trying to make one but isnt one. I tried and found that my Explorer CPU usage goes to 10%, nearly. It usually floats around .5% or so never close to 10%.

Comment: xperf also works in Win8. provide the ETL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be caused by the fact that your integrated graphics card is not allowing your GTX to do it's thing but the GTX is like a women and is all like "I can do my thing if I want". So I would recommend looking at [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_6002987_bypass-integrated-graphics-card.html).

Comment: I did what you stated about the graphics card clashing. It seemed to work. Most others thought it was flash and crap, which it wasn't as was happening with other things not just flash videos.

Comment: Glad I could help! The thing with integrated graphics is it's a hit or miss situation. I'm glad this time it was a hit.